# 3D rendering a 2D cylinder in blender or three.js?

Tags: three.js, blender

I'm curious if it's possible to render this object, for the purposes of being exported and used in three.js

[pic of cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p9Jm.png)

Seemed simple at the time, but I've been having a lot of trouble getting it to work. I was able to get close to what I wanted with Blender's "freestyle lines", but they aren't exportable.

[cylinder in blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYHSB.png)

It looks like I will have to make a custom material or something like that, but I was wondering if there was a more straightforward way I haven't seen. I tried Three's "wireframe" and "EdgeGeometry" tools, but I'm trying to avoid rendering the interior edges of the model.

And it seems really difficult to make a mathematically perfect cylinder outline from a UV, unless there's something I'm not seeing!

Anyways, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how correct this approach is, but its result is almost similar
 to what is shown on the picture you provided.

[Reference](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=material#webgl_materials_variations_toon)

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 3, 5).setLength(400);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setClearColor(0x999999);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
effect = new THREE.OutlineEffect(renderer);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(100, 100, 200, 32), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "white"
}));
scene.add(cylinder);

var lid = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(99, 99, 0.001, 32), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "white"
}));
lid.geometry.translate(0, 101.0, 0);
scene.add(lid);

var lid2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(99, 99, 0.001, 32), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "white"
}));
lid2.geometry.translate(0, -101.0, 0);
scene.add(lid2);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  effect.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/effects/OutlineEffect.js"></script>
```